# PTIJ: why are fast people singled out after Yom Kippur/tisha b’av

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

After Yom Kippur and Tisha B’av Jews are supposed to break the fast. But why single out the fast people? Is there something about them that makes them more deserving of punishment than slow or medium paced people?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply because the fast people get to the cake and orange juice before everyone else. So there's nothing left for the slowpokes.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. [Too fast or merubah, lo tofasto](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%A1%D7%AA_%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%91%D7%94_%D7%9C%D7%90_%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%A1%D7%AA).